# Check if many URLs exists from a txt file (Python)

Tags: python, url

i'm new in python and I'm wanting to do what I said above, but I don't have any ideas, so how can I?

Comment: What does the txt file look like?

Comment: Please at least try to analyse the problem before asking for help. If you have some specific problem then ask here.

Comment: Ooh sorry guys, the txt file include a list of URL per line. for example. "Google.com , Microsoft.com" Each per line.

Comment: [When you tried solving this yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), with which part did you get stuck? Opening the file? Reading in the file and finding things that looked like URLs? Validating the URLs? If you provide some code, we are more likely to be able to help. Note that "Google.com" is a domain name, not a URL.

Comment: I'm using the mechanize module, and the "google.com" was a example, sorry. The code is below.




import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_redirect(False)
try:
 br.open_novisit('http://www.google.com.br')
 print 'Funfando!'
except:
 print 'Not Found...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code in your comment (you should put this in your question), it is with reading the lines from a file that you're struggling.

The idiomatic way of doing this is like so:

```
with open("hello.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

[See [**File Objects**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) in [the official Python documentation]](http://docs.python.org/).

Plugging this into your code (and removing the newline and any spaces from each line with [**`str.strip()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_redirect(False)
with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        stripped = url.strip()
        print '[{}]: '.format(stripped),
        try:
            br.open_novisit(stripped)
            print 'Funfando!'
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

Note that URLs start with a *scheme name* (commonly called a *protocol*, such as `http`), followed by a colon, and two slashes hence:

> [stackoverflow.com]:  can't fetch relative reference: not viewing any document

But

> [http://stackoverflow.com/]:  Funfando!

Comment: Wow! Absolutely awesome, thanks man! How Can I learn more?! I'm much confuse where to find documentations about it. I really want have you as a contact, here my skype: Themilbol

Comment: Happy to have helped. I've referenced the official documentation in my answer, that is a good starting point and includes an excellent [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) the file. [Iterate through the lines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects). [Fetch the files](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) and check for errors.